# PySpark - adding a column to count(*)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I Have the below script (i've removed all the column names etc.. to make it easier to see what I am doing at a high level - it was very messy!!)

I need to add a column that is the equivalent of count(*) in SQL.

So if I have grouped user usage by domain I might see the below - where the count is the number of records that match all the prior column conditiosn.

domain.co.uk/       UK User   32433
domain.co.uk/home   EU User   43464
etc...

I'm sure it's been asked somewhere on Stackoverflow before, but I've had a good look around and cant find any reference to it!

```
vpx_cont_filter = vpx_data\
        .coalesce(1000)\
        .join(....)\
        .select(....)\
        .groupBy(....)\
        .agg(
           ....
            )\
        .select(....)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean that in your agg, you want to add a column that counts all occurences for each groupBy ?

You can add this then :

```
.agg(
  F.count(F.lit(1)).alias("total_count"),
  ...
)
```

By the way, I don't think you're forced to use **F.lit(1)**. In the Spark source code, the have a match case if you specify the star instead of **F.lit(1)**

```
// Turn count(*) into count(1)
  case s: Star => Count(Literal(1))
  case _ => Count(e.expr)
```

So **F.count("*")** would also work I think

***PS :*** I'm using **F.** because I assumed you imported the functions package like this

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```